# twilio - need to play an mp3 for caller

Tags: twilio, twilio-php

I need to play mp3 file for a caller.
In my website I have a section where I upload files for each number that I bought by twilio. Now I need to connect this files with twilio. As soos as someone calls by this number, that files must be played.

Comment: Did you check the docs? Because it's in the docs.

Comment: I'd say... no they didn't.

Answer (score 3):

To play an MP3 file once the Twilio call connects you need to use the following Twiml. The key here is the `<Play>` verb.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <Play>URL TO YOUR MP3 FILE</Play>
</Response>
```

As an example from the Twilio Docs:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <Play loop="10">https://api.twilio.com/cowbell.mp3</Play>
</Response>
```

I'd highly recommend reading the Twilo documentation, it's outstanding!

https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/play

Comment: each phone number has its own file

Comment: Ok that's fine. You'd have to create a file for each number, that is accessible at specific URLs. You then configure your Twilio application to point to that file depending on the number dialled.

Comment: There are a lot of numbers. it must be dynamic. I must not configure it via Twilio account.

Comment: Ok then configure the endpoint for all numbers to go to the same PHP file and use PHP to insert a different file name depending on the number. Have you tried writing any code to achieve this?

Comment: I just need to add "VoiceUrl" to already bought number via api, but i can't find it.

Comment: So you want to pass a parameter (Containing the MP3 URL) to your TWIML script?

Comment: You can update the VoiceUrl of a phone number by POSTing to the phone number's endpoint. Check out the docs here: https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/incoming-phone-numbers#instance-post